# tensorflow ANN not matching my expected output variables

Tags: python, neural-network, output, layer

I am doing a Multivariate Regression with an ANN using Keras/Tensorflow.
My dataset is (32686, 49), I think there's enough information to train/test (80/20).
I have 22 input variables and I am expecting 27 output variables.
Prior to training, the input variables have been standardized.

This is my configuration. I've added L2 regularization and Dropout layers (as the initial training showed overfitting).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(22, input_dim=22, activation=activation,kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='mish', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='mish', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(27, activation='relu'))
```

These are some other hyperparameters I'm using.
Initially I trained for 50 epochs but I saw there might be a chance for improvement. So I increased it and added early stopping if no change on the mse is observed.

```
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=Adam,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    
early_stopping_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='mse',
                                                        patience=10,
                                                        restore_best_weights=True)
    
model_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                          epochs=100,
                          batch_size=32,
                          validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                          verbose=1,
                          callbacks=[early_stopping_callback])
```

For the latest run, I got these results and I was feeling quite good with them (compared to first runs).

|  | Result |
| --- | --- |
| epochs | 100 |
| loss | 1637.536 |
| mae | 5.973 |
| mse | 1637.536 |
| val_loss | 1526.601 |
| val_mae | 6.14 |
| val_mse | 1526.601 |

I am using the trained model with fresh data for validation, not used in training/testing to predict new data. The input data is also standardized (as in the training).

```
ypred_new = model.predict(X_new)
```

I get results that seem around the values I'm expecting.

However, when I'm trying to calculate the R2 score,

```
R2_model = r2_score(Y_val, ypred_new)
```

I realized the output does not match to what I am expecting, by receiving this error:

```
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (27!=22)
```

So, as the title says, I should have 27 output variables; I set 27 neurons in the ouput layer, and as far as I am aware, the setup was alright.
Now I'm wondering:

- Am I missing something?
- Have I skipped something critical?
- Have I misconfigured some hyperparameters?

Any feedback or comment is most welcome.